# Accessing a UIImage from a Texture Atlas in Cocos2D

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, uiimage, textures

My project is using a Texture Atlas for sprite animations in Cocos2D.  But now, I need to access one frame of pixel data from the Atlas.  Is there a way to extract a single animation "frame" from the larger Atlas file as a UIImage?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a UIImage category for handling sprite sheets. Check out this, it may be helpful http://reecon.wordpress.com/2011/11/19/uiimage-sprite-additions-objective-c/

As noted earlier, this category bases on *CGImageCreateWithImageInRect()* but makes the process of extracting sprites from a single sprite sheet far more convenient and faster.